# Am I crazy for thinking this program is O(n) runtime? My TA says it's O(n^2)

Tags: big-o

Code below, it should be O(n). **There are two loops, I know this.** But that doesn't necessarily mean it's O(n^2). The function loops won't run more than n + 1 times (at least as far as I can tell!). That should be O(n). Am I wrong? Can someone help me out? Thanks!

EDIT: The program puts odd integers at the front and even integers at the back of an array!!!

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] array = new int[]{5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    organizeArray(array);

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(array[j]);
    }

}

public static void organizeArray(int[] array) {

    int end = array.length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        int temp = 0;

        while (true) {

            if (i == end)
                break;

            if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {

                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[end];
                array[end] = temp;
                end = end - 1;
            }

            if (array[i] % 2 != 0)
                break;

        }

        if (i == end)
            break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: For each run of the inner while loop, either the end is decremented or i is incremented. So if the inner loop runs n times on the 1st iteration of the outer loop, the outer loop will run only on that first run. I don't see how this can ever be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064441/is-this-program-on-or-on2) was a duplicate of this one, let me post my answer here.

The code is O(n) as you either increase `i` or reduce `end`. In any case, you decrease the rest of work (n) by one.

For your upcoming homework: You can test your thoughts about big-O easily just by trying out. Most of the time the number of tests doesn't need to be very big. It will not be a proof but it gives you a good hint if your thoughts are correct or not.

Here's is my code for your problem with 100 tests. It produces 100 pairs of numbers: The length of the array and the number of loops. You take this list and bring it to a graph.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int[] array = new int[random.nextInt(10000 - 10) + 10]; // between 10 and 9999 numbers long
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) array[j] = random.nextInt();

            main.organize(array);
        }
    }

    private int[] organize(int[] array) {
        long loops = 0;
        int end = array.length-1;

        // I've shorten your code here. This does the same with less breaks
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            while(i < end && array[i] % 2 == 0) {
                swap(array, i, end--);
                loops++;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", array.length, loops);
        return array;
    }

    private void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
        int t = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = t;
    }
}
```

And the graph looks like a straight line. So your proof should result in O(n), right?

[image: O(n) by simply trying out]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting code. The inner for loop will break when the `i`'th element is odd. If its not odd then it will swap elements from the `end` until an odd one is found. Since `end` is decremented upon each swap and the program completes when `i` reaches `end`, it follows that `i` or `end` can get incremented/decremented, respectively at most O(n) times. Because of this, and because all other operations in the loops are O(1), the program indeed runs in time O(n) despite there being nested loops.

Comment: Why are a lot of people saying it's O(n^2) then :/

Comment: I am unsure. What is their reasoning for saying that?

Comment: Some said it's because there are two nested loops, it has to be O(n^2). My TA also is telling me it's O(n^2), reasoning is "Algorithm runs maximum of O(n*n) because of the inner while loop. You
        actually don't need it for the algorithm to work. Need to add case
        if a[i] is odd or end is even"

Comment: I don't know exactly what your TA said, but as stated those arguments are very weak and lack real explanation. The statement "there are two nested for loops therefore it must be O(n^2)" is blatantly false.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for your feedback!