# What is the complexity of this nested loop?

Tags: big-o

I always been under the assumption that nested loops are always O(N^2). But this code that I wrote recently is clearly not that, what is the complexity of this code?

```
emails  = [test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com, test3@gmail.com]
for i in range (0, len(emails):
   for j in range(0, len(emails[i]):
```

Is this O(N^2) or am I incorrect?

Comment: Look a little deep than just the loops *you* wrote here (hint: peek at the source of `range()`)

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are **not always** O(N^2). See an old post of mine for an example: [Am I crazy for thinking this program is O(n) runtime? My TA says it's O(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037187/am-i-crazy-for-thinking-this-program-is-on-runtime-my-ta-says-its-on2)

In your case, is the length of emails[i] dependent upon the size of your emails array(which you are calling n)?

Answer (score 0):

Because the length of the strings themselves factors into the complexity, you can only create an upper-bound time complexity if you have an upper-bound for the length of the strings.

let **n** = the number of strings in your array

let **m** = the maximum length of any string in the array

In that case it would be **O(nm)** complexity.

This assumes you're not doing above O(1) in the innermost loop you've shown.

If you can't guarantee an upper-bound size of your strings, the time is **unbounded**, since a string could in theory be infinitely long.